# Searching for product with dash doesn't work in Magento 2

Tags: catalogsearch, elasticsearch, magento2.4.5

I am working on Magento 2.4.5. I have a product named **'T-24'**. When I search with this name expected product does not appear after the search. But When I search for any product without **'-'** in it like **'C783'** that product shows up. Can anyone help me out with this search problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this option. You have to apply a patch...

https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360050671611-MDVA-28993-Magento-patch-Elasticsearch-partial-search-minimum-should-match-and-fix-for-searches-with-hyphen-issue

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't comment the solution above, so I add my comment here :

Unfortunately the suggested patch MDVA-28993 does not work. It applies only for Magento 2.3. This patch is already applied from Magento 2.4 and the bug is still present.

I completed the issue on github, but unfortunately none seems to care :
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9988

Could anybody help with this please ? It's a critical bug.
Thank you.

EDIT : I think I found a solution, see my last comment on the github issue : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9988#issuecomment-1637645647